# How to set permissions using facebook/php-sdk-v4

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using `$session = new FacebookSession('access token here');`, I've manage to retrieve my profile as described in `https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/profilewithgraphapi/4.0.0`.

so I have a `$session`. Problem is that when I tried the example to post links as in the example code docs, I don't have the right permission for `publish_actions`.

```
if($session) {

  try {

    $response = (new FacebookRequest(
      $session, 'POST', '/me/feed', array(
        'link' => 'www.example.com',
        'message' => 'User provided message'
      )
    ))->execute()->getGraphObject();

    echo "Posted with id: " . $response->getProperty('id');

  } catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {

    echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
    echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();

  }   

}
```

I've searched the web for answers but most deal with outdated codes and using `Logins` and/or `redirect urls` to obtain the token and therefore no longer work with the recent api.

Any ideas as to how I can set permissions using the obtained session above so I can ran the post link example above?

Comment: You ask for permissions when the user login

Comment: @WizKid the user already logged in via `$session = new FacebookSession('access token here');` that's why there's already a session.

Comment: But that access token doesn't have the permission.

Comment: @WizKid it comes with the default permission. I just want to know how to add more permissions to it since [facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0) allows to have 4 helper classes options to get a session. login is one but I used the fourth one which is the access token.

Comment: The access token already contains the permissions you have. You need to ask for permissions before the access token is created\

Comment: @WizKid I see. So in that case, I can't use the 4th option. thought I can get away without the login option.

Comment: Of course you can't get away with the login option. You need login for the user to be able to grant you the permissions you need. If you don't have login you will have no idea who the person is on Facebook